# cPanel usage of separate javascript and php files

Tags: javascript, php, cpanel

I have a HTML form and when a specific radiobox is selected and submitted I need to +1 to a value on the same HTML page. However, I need this to be a global change (so the change is visable to other browsers and users).

I've looked into this and looks like .php is best option for this but I haven't managed to get it working exactly how I want.

This is basically how I think it should work (It may be that it never works like this):

[image]

The area where I am struggling is sending the variable to the .php and getting the variable back from the .php. Am I correct in thinking that the php will store the variable as the latest value it gets? So, if the variable in the php changes to '4', then no matter what browser or user views it, the variable will always be '4' until it changes again?

Currently the HTML works exactly how it should and is displayed on a webpage through cPanel. I believe cPanel supports .php.

I can read a variable from the php if it is in html (saved as .php), and also if the javascript function is also in the html. I want to have the html, javascript and php as 3 separate documents.

I've tried to explain this as best as I can, if it isn't clear please let me know and I will try to answer any questions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would be useful to see some code as well, especially on how you send and retrieve the value. For example, are you posting the current value via JavaScript (i.e. AJAX) or forms?